# Efficient JDBC connection management in a stateless session bean

Tags: java, jdbc, ejb

I have a stateless session bean a method of which is used repetitively for running an SQL query within a plain JDBC connection. To avoid having to open and close connections too frequently, I came up with the following approach and wondering if it is a good practice:

I open the connection once in a method annotated @PostConstruct and close the connection in another method annotated @PreDestroy

The code works fine with no apparent memory leaks or any issues that I know of - just wondering if more experienced developers would agree if it is a good practice.

```
@PostConstruct
public void initBean() {
   try {
      conn = Connector.getConnection();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

public String runTheQuery(String sql) {
   String result ="";
   try {
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
      result = rs.getString(1);
      rs.close();
      pstmt.close();
   } catch (SQLException se) {
      // Handle errors for JDBC
   }
   return result;
}

@PreDestroy
public void endingTitles() {
   System.out.println("Closing the JDBC connection...");
   try {
      rs.close();
      conn.close();
      pstmt.close();
   } catch (SQLException se) {
      // Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
            // finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (pstmt != null)
                    pstmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
            }// nothing we can do
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }// end finally try
        }// end try
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is to use DataSource

```
@Resource(mappedName="java:/DefaultDS")
DataSource dataSource;

public String runTheQuery(String sql) throws SQLException 
    Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
    try {
       ...
    } finally {
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not avoid opening a connection every time the runTheQuery() method is invoked - in this case the method is meant to be called repetitively like 100000 times in a loop from a controller class.

Comment: DataSources are typically connection pools, they reuse connections, con.close just returns it to the pool.

Answer (score 1):

Data sources normally always have a minimum number of open connections, so in most cases there will be no real overhead getting a connection from a data source.

So it's only a valid practice, if you have measured before, and it it really **solves an existing performance problem**.

Otherwise it's **not common**, and therefore it's something like premature performance optimization.

Data sources offer additonal functionality: For example to check a connection, if it's still valid, before it gets injected. If you did it yourself, you would have to reimplement it. And there are possibly errors in that code.